# maximize $\int \limits ^b_a (24 - 2x - x^2)^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to find $a$ and $b$ in $\int \limits ^b_a $(24 - 2$x$ - $x^2$)$^{1/3}dx$ such that the value of the integral is maximized.

I know I need to solve the integral, plug in $a$ and $b$, and then treat the result as a function of two variables, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: $$24-2x-x^2=5^2-(2x-1)^2$$ Put $2x-1=5\sin\theta$

Comment: This integral doesn't have an elementary antiderivative, so you're going to want to try something different.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think that works.

Comment: **Hint**: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Following up on the first post, you can notice that the cube root of a negative number is negative, so it makes sense to choose the two endpoints where the quantity 25-(2x-1)$^2$ $\geq$ 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to find the largest interval on which your function is non-negative. No integration!

**Remark:** We have tacitly assumed that $a\le b$. If we allow $a\gt b$. there is no maximum. For example, by taking $b=4$ and $a$ large positive, we can make $\int_a^4 f(x)\,dx$ arbitrarily large.

Comment: (Further hint: factor the quadratic!)

Comment: So the interval on which $24 - 2x - x^2$ is positive will be the max for the integral?

Comment: Yes, because when you step outside that region, you are "adding" negative stuff. In the interval $[-6,4]$ our function is $\ge 0$, outside it the function is negative.

Comment: But then if $ b < a $ it is good to have negative area. Its maximum is positive infinity if you allow $ b < a $.

Answer (score 2):

The question really just boils down to finding the roots of the quadratic, however, slightly more generally, let 
$$
F(a,b) = \int^b_a \! (24-2x-x^2)^{1/3} \ \mathrm{d}x,
$$
and assume that the real root is used when considering negative values for the randicand, rather than principle values. Using multivariable optimisation methods, and by the FTC,
$$
{\partial F \over \partial b} = (24-2b-b^2)^{1/3}, 
$$
$$
{\partial F \over \partial a} = -(24-2a-a^2)^{1/3}.
$$
When these are both equal to zero, $b=-6$ or $b=4$, and $a=-6$ or $a=4$. Assuming that $a<b$ gives us that $a=-6$, $b=4$.